# FileInfo.Length dá o tamanho errado

Tags: c#, arquivo, byte

Estou a tentar adicionar a thumbnail, o nome e o tamanho de um ficheiro a uma `ListView`. Eu consigo adicionar tudo corretamente, excepto o tamanho!

Estou a fazer `Split` do PDF e vou adicionando as informações de cada página à `ListView`.

Os valores que aparecem no "Tamanho" são **0 ou um valor errado**, que eu penso ser o tamanho do nome do ficheiro, e não o tamanho do ficheiro em si.

Vou mostrar o meu código e as diferenças entre dar o valor 0 ou valor errado.

**VALOR 0:**

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(input);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(input);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    //get thumbnail from 1st page-----------------------------------------------------
    string pastapdf = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "temporario\\Thumbnails";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(pastapdf);
    using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(input))
    {
        var image = document.Render(i-1, 60, 84, 300, 300, true);
        image.Save(pastapdf + "\\" + name + "Pagina" + i + "_thumbnail" + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        thumbnails.Images.Add(j.ToString(), image);
        image.Dispose();
        document.Dispose();
    }
    //split pdf-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    string p = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "temporario\\" + name + " - Pagina " + i + ".PDF";
    Stream outputStream = new FileStream(p, FileMode.Create);

    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, outputStream);
    doc.Open();
    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.DirectContent;
    PdfImportedPage importedpage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle mediabox = reader.GetPageSize(i);

    doc.SetPageSize(mediabox);
    doc.NewPage();
    pdfContentByte.AddTemplate(importedpage, 0, 0);

    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(p);
    ListViewItem _item1 = new ListViewItem();
    _item1.ImageKey = j.ToString();
    _item1.Text = name + " - Pagina " + i + ".PDF";
    _item1.SubItems.Add(f.Length.ToString()); //diferença está aui

    lista2.Items.Add(_item1);

    outputStream.Flush();
    doc.Close();
    doc.Dispose();
    outputStream.Close();
    pdfWriter.Dispose();
    j++;
```

[image: Valor 0]

**VALOR ERRADO:**

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(input);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(input);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    //get thumbnail from 1st page-----------------------------------------------------
    string pastapdf = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "temporario\\Thumbnails";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(pastapdf);
    using (var document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(input))
    {
        var image = document.Render(i-1, 60, 84, 300, 300, true);
        image.Save(pastapdf + "\\" + name + "Pagina" + i + "_thumbnail" + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        thumbnails.Images.Add(j.ToString(), image);
        image.Dispose();
        document.Dispose();
    }
    //split pdf-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    string p = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "temporario\\" + name + " - Pagina " + i + ".PDF";
    Stream outputStream = new FileStream(p, FileMode.Create);

    Document doc = new Document();
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, outputStream);
    doc.Open();
    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.DirectContent;
    PdfImportedPage importedpage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle mediabox = reader.GetPageSize(i);

    doc.SetPageSize(mediabox);
    doc.NewPage();
    pdfContentByte.AddTemplate(importedpage, 0, 0);

    FileInfo f = new FileInfo(p);
    ListViewItem _item1 = new ListViewItem();
    _item1.ImageKey = j.ToString();
    _item1.Text = name + " - Pagina " + i + ".PDF";
    _item1.SubItems.Add(p.Length.ToString()); //diferença está aqui

    lista2.Items.Add(_item1);

    outputStream.Flush();
    doc.Close();
    doc.Dispose();
    outputStream.Close();
    pdfWriter.Dispose();
    j++;
```

[image: Valor errado]

Desde já, agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está medindo o tamanho da string e não o tamanho do arquivo, o problema não está no `FileInfo.Length` mas sim no seu código.

Agora se o `FileInfo.Length` está retornando 0 bytes para você, é porque ainda está com o stream aberto e não persistiu o conteúdo deles no disco.

Como você apresentou no segundo bloco:

```
string p = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "temporario\\" + name + " - Pagina " + i + ".PDF";
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(p);
ListViewItem _item1 = new ListViewItem();
_item1.ImageKey = j.ToString();
_item1.Text = name + " - Pagina " + i + ".PDF";
_item1.SubItems.Add(p.Length.ToString()); //diferença está aqui
```

`FileInfo.Length` irá retornar o tamanho do arquivo em bytes desde que o conteúdo já tenha sido escrito nos arquivos. Feche os streams e os writes antes de vericá-los novamente.

```
outputStream.Flush();
doc.Close();
doc.Dispose();
outputStream.Close();
pdfWriter.Dispose();

FileInfo f = new FileInfo(p);
ListViewItem _item1 = new ListViewItem();
_item1.ImageKey = j.ToString();
_item1.Text = name + " - Pagina " + i + ".PDF";
_item1.SubItems.Add(f.Length.ToString()); //a diferença estava aqui
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta @Leandro, mas se colocar `f.Length.ToString()` devolve sempre o valor 0 e não o tamanho real do ficheiro.

Comment: @SofiaRodrigues Veja a edição da resposta

Comment: Agora que editou o código, ficou tudo mais claro e era de facto a questão de fechar a stream e os writes antes! Muito obrigada!